# DataExtension.Retrieve() returns undefined

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I'm trying to get this variable in my cloudPage ("allDataExtensions") to return an array of all data extension objects in my org. The original formula I was using was as follows

Original Formula

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1");
var allDataExtensions = DataExtension.Retrieve({Property: "IsSendable", SimpleOperator: "equals", Value: "True"});
</script>
```

However, this wasn't working...So i tried doing a simple POC to see if it'd work if i used customerKey like the examples they have in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_dataExtensionRetrieve.htm) so i updated it to something similar (i replaced the external key for the DE, but you get the point)

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1");
var allDataExtensions = DataExtension.Retrieve({Property: "CustomerKey", SimpleOperator: "equals", Value: "INSERT DE EXTERNAL KEY"});
</script>
```

Even with replicating the example in the documentation, i'm still finding this returns "undefined" to my cloudpage - can anyone let me know their thoughts as to why this may not be working and if there's a better method for getting an array of all Data Extension objects

Comment: How are you outputting it that is showing undefined? Are you Stringifying it before Writing? This returns a JSON object, which is not something that can be directly output to the page, you would need to turn it into a String or similar format to be able to have it be able to be written

Comment: Thanks @Gortonington after stringifying the variable it outputted the result on the page

Answer (score 0):

Changing from Comment to Answer for easier reference:

Are you Stringifying it before Writing?

`allDataExtensions` returns as a JSON object, which is not something that can be directly output to the page. If you tried, it would come back as undefined as it is not a recognizable file type for Write to display.

To Write his, you would need to turn it into a String or similar format to be able to have it be able to be written.

You can use the Stringify() function to transform this to a string so it can be displayed.

```js
Platfrom.Function.Stringify(allDataExtensions)
```

There are other options, but these each fail on nested JSON arrays/objects - so Stringify is the best one to choose for consistent results.